# How to clear a textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a

```
<input type="text" value="A new value">
```

I need a javascript method to clear the value of the textbox when the focus is on the
textbox.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use a "watermark" (a default value that clears itself when the user focuses on the box).  Make sure to check the value before clearing it, otherwise you might remove something they have typed in!  Try this:

```
<input type="text" value="A new value" onfocus="if(this.value=='A new value') this.value='';">
```

That will ensure it only clears when the value is "A new value".

Comment: This solves the problem. however, I have a cancel button which should set the text bac to "A New value". Another javascript method?

Comment: @Kalls: If that cancel button is a normal `<input type="reset">`, then it should do that.

Comment: RoToRa is correct, a "reset" button should do the trick.  If you're using a custom JS function to "cancel", add this code to it:  `document.getElementById('IDofthetextbox').value = "A new value";`

Comment: I have a Jquery method on the cancel button which hides a DIV. How can I write code to identify and set the text of the textbox?

Comment: @Kalls: You'll need to give the input an ID and put this inside that method:  `$('#mytextbox').val('');` where 'mytextbox' is the ID.

Comment: It would make more sense to use the `placeholder` attribute and avoid the need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 50):

just get element using

```
   function name()
   {  
   document.getElementById('elementid').value = "";
   }
```

you can call this function on onfocus event of textbox and clear the value

Answer (score 11):

For those coming across this nowadays, this is what the `placeholder` attribute was made to do. No JS necessary:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="A new value">
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<input type="text" value="A new value" onfocus="javascript: if(this.value == 'A new value'){ this.value = ''; }" onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='A new value';}" />
```

Comment: You should really be using the placeholder='' attribute, though

Answer (score 8):

just set empty string

```
    <input type="text" id="textId" value="A new value">
    document.getElementById('textId').value = '';
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple one

```
onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Search...';}"
```

Comment: The 'javascript:' label in the intrinsic events are absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: this is just like a placeholder and optional

Comment: You really don’t need to add JavaScript:

Answer (score 6):

use sth like

`<input type="text" name="yourName" placeholder="A new value" />`

Answer (score 5):

If using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is acceptable:

```
jQuery("#myTextBox").focus( function(){ 
    $(this).val(""); 
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this in input tag of textbox:

```
onClick="(this.value='')"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" value="A new value" onfocus="this.value='';">
```

However this will be very irrigating for users that focus the element a second time e.g. to correct something.

Answer (score 2):

Use the onfocus and onblur events like this:

```
<input type="text" name="yourName" value="A new value" onfocus="if (this.value == 'A new value') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'A new value';">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="yourName" value="A new value" onfocus="if (this.value == 'A new value') this.value =='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') alert('Please enter a value');" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Onfous And onblur Text box with javascript**

```
   <input type="text" value="A new value" onfocus="if(this.value=='A new value') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='A new value';"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code,

jquery code,

$("#textboxID").val('');

Comment: This is jQuery and not exactly what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

For my coffeescript peeps!

```
#disable Delete button until reason is entered
$("#delete_event_button").prop("disabled", true)
$('#event_reason_is_deleted').click ->
    $('#event_reason_is_deleted').val('')
    $("#delete_event_button").prop("disabled", false)
```