# Clear TextBox in Login Control when onclick

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have login control and textbox inside , i need to write UserName in textbox to show to user and i need when click inside textbox to clear this textbox and allow user to enter text[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108207/how-do-i-make-an-html-text-box-show-a-hint-when-empty

Comment: This link has all you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135818/how-to-clear-a-textbox-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for javascript code

```
<input type="text" value="your name" name="usrname" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
```

Comment: i need to change textmode to password after clearing the textbox

Comment: @KareemMouneir i could not understand your question

Answer (score 1):

use the [placeholder html5](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute

Answer (score 1):

**if using jQuery is acceptable:**

```
jQuery("#myTextBox").focus( function(){ 
    $(this).val(""); 
} );
```

**or in javascript**

```
<input type="text" value="A new value" onfocus="javascript: if(this.value == 'A new value'){ this.value = ''; }" onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='A new value';}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Last year I wrote a jQuery plugin for exact that problem. It's called "toggletextfieldvalue" check it out http://www.naden.de/blog/toggle-textfield-value-jquery-plugin

Note: If you are using HTML5, you can rely on the new `placeholder` attribute.