# In ASP.NET can you String.Empty the TextBox thats IN focus?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, textbox

wondering if this is possible, currently using this to click a 'clear' button, then it clears UPIN;

```
Protected Sub clear(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
UPIN.Text=String.Empty
End Sub
```

But I want it to clear whichever textbox is in focus! for example;

```
focusedstring.Text=String.Empty
```

Again is it possible without masses of JS or anything?

Comment: You can find the answer here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135818/how-to-clear-a-textbox-using-javascript

This shouldn't be too hard to adapt to your needs :)

And I clicked delete instead of Edit a second ago :(

Answer (score 3):

You should do it on **client side** (edit: as suggested by MightyLampshade you can find on of 1000 examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135818/how-to-clear-a-textbox-using-javascript)), you do not need a round-trip to server for that. If you have, let's say, a clear button:

```
$("#clear").click(function() {
    $(".can-be-cleared").val("");
});
```

Please note that this will clear all elements with class `can-be-cleared` (I assume you may do not want to clear each input but a specific set, if it's not the case just replace it with `input[type=text]`).when you click an element with id `clear`.

If each "clear" button has to be tied with a single specific text box then you have to repeat them (because when you click on the button textbox won't be focused any more). As alternative you may *remember* last focused text box. Let's see both:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
<button class="clear-button" data-textbox="textbox1">clear</button>
```

JavaScript for this is:

```
$(".clear-button").click(function() {
    $("#"+$(this).data("textbox")).val("");
});
```

**Simpler alternative** (I prefer this if you do not have any other special requirement) may be to keep track of last focused textbox:

```
var lastFocused = undefined;

$("input[type=text]").focus(function () {
    lastFocused = $(this);
});

$("#clear-field").click(function () {
    if (lastFocused !== undefined) {
        lastFocused.val("");
    }
});
```

Of course do not forget to match `$("#clear-field")` with right ID you used for your clear button, in this case I assume:

```
<button id="clear-field">Clear</button>
```

Anyway if you really need some server side processing (for any other reason), `TextBox` that generated event is in `sender` parameter:

```
Dim textbox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
textbox.Text = String.Empty
```

Comment: Hi, there are 3 fields, A B and C, all edited in turn, I want to clear whichever is in focus so they dont need to do A and B again if they are on C.

Currently trying, does this line seem correct; $(input[type=text]).val("");

Thanks

Comment: @Kieronboz yes, if you have just three textboxes you can omit class in query so it'll be (don't forget quotes): `$("input[type=text]").val("");` (and don't forget to change `#clear` to the right ID of your clear button). What I don't understand is: **do you want to clear them with a clear button or when they receive focus**?

Comment: Hi again, I want them to clear if they want too due to a mistake, so they are inputting data, they get it wrong, click clear, it deletes the characters in the field they are typing in. Rather than just using UPIN.Text=String.Empty. 3 times for ABC

Comment: @Kieronboz ok, got it. There are (at least!) two options for that, I updated answers with some code examples.

Answer (score -1):

can you try this:

```
 $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
      $(this).val('');
      });
```

Its simple with Jquery..no need to write masses of lines of code.

**Updated:**

If you do want to Clear on button click:

```
  $("#Clear").click(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
      $(this).val('');
      });    
});
```

Comment: Hi which variable here references my Clear ASP Button? Thanks

Comment: @Kieronboz..As per your requirement . Here, this resfers to the textbox which is focussed..

Comment: Hi @Avinash yeah thats great, but I cant see how I link this to my button, so that WHEN i click the button, it deletes the text in focus. Thanks!

Comment: @Kieronboz..just assign a class to all those fields. Then just use $(.classname).val('');

Comment: Hi, but then wont that clear all 3? I only want to clear the one field in focus