# How to clear the text of asp:TextBox when user again open the pop up window?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I follow [How to clear a textbox using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135818/how-to-clear-a-textbox-using-javascript) but my scenario is little change. I have a login button and when user click on login a pop-up window is open. He fill the textbox and for some reason he go back to main page. When he again come to login popup window he previous value is not cleared. May be this is because the page is not loaded. And I do not want to load page again. I want to use JQuery/JavaScript to remove the entered text. I has idea that I write code inside Close button but I don't know how to clear the textboxes. Please help.

Here is the code, scenario is that I used popup for login and sign up. In login popup there is link "Don't have login Id" when user click on it the sign up pop up with form is open.

```
<a href="#" id="signUp" onclick="function_deletePreviousData">Don't have Login Id</a>
```

And the JavaScript method is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function function_deletePreviousData(){
            document.getElementById("signUp").value = "";
        }
    </script>
```

But nothing happened. I think this is because I don't give element id, I just give id of element which I used to land on sign up pop up form. Any idea for clear all form without accessing all elements and give it null value.

Comment: Without seeing your current code I doubt we could be helpful...

Comment: if you mentioned your code it will be easy to find solution for the problem...

Comment: RunningFromShia and Enoch I add code please review and give some idea. Advance thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find the method in JQuery to reset all fields. Just Trigger reset.

```
$('#form').trigger("reset");
```

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of including code in close button click event, we should write code in login button click.This is one of my suggestion.

Try this once:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function LoginButtonClick() {
    document.getElementById`("TextBox_Id").value = "";
 }
</script>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery("#LoginButton_Id").Click( function()
{ 
  $('#TextBox_Id').val(""); 
} );
```

Comment: Dear, I write same as you said. But nothing happened.
<script type="text/javascript">
        function function_deletePreviousData(){
            document.getElementById("signUp").value = "";
        }
    </script> and the line which calls the function is : <a href="#" id="signUp" onclick="function_deletePreviousData">Don't have Login Id</a>

Comment: In this statement  document.getElementById("**signUp**").value = "";,please mention your textbox id not your anchor tag id.

Comment: yup its working, now I have 20 textboxes and with this way I write 20 statements in JavaScript function. Is there any way or method in JavaScript/JQuery to clear all data of form.